# Diffie-Hellman with BIGNUM (OpenSSL) vs. BigInteger (C#)

Tags: c#, c, openssl, biginteger, diffie-hellman

I'm implementing a [Diffie-Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) key exchange algorithm between an embedded device which uses OpenSSL libraries for `BIGNUM` operations and a C# software which uses `System.Numerics.BigInteger` methods to calculate the secret shared key generation.

But after Alice and Bob exchange keys, they calculate different shared secrets.

The keys are printed out on each side `(PubA, PrivA, PubB, PrivB, DHPrime, DHGenerator)` and I can see that they are the same.

I suspect there is an issue about little/big endianness, or maybe openssl doesn't care about negative numbers for the exponent, and I don't know how to debug those operations. I don't have the code with me right now, but all the operations are kept simple, like this.

**C# side**

```
BigInteger bintA = new BigInteger(baByteArrayReceived);
BigInteger bintb = new BigInteger(baRandomBobSecret);
BigInteger bintDHPrime = new BigInteger(baDHPrime2048);

BigInteger bintSharedSecret = bintA.ModPow(bintb,bintDHPrime);
```

**C side**

```
BIGNUM *bnB = BN_new();
BIGNUM *bna = BN_new();
BIGNUM *bnDHPrime = BN_new();
BIGNUM *bnResult = BN_new();
BN_CTX *bnctx = BN_CTX_new();

BN_bin2bn(baBReceived, 256,bnB);
BN_bin2bn(baRandomAliceSecret, 256,bna);
BN_bin2bn(baDHPrime2048, 256,bnDHPrime);

BN_mod_exp(bnResult,bnB,bna,bnDHPrime,bnctx);
```

Some additional info for C methods of OpenSSL:
>

> ```
> BIGNUM *BN_bin2bn(const uint8_t *in, size_t len, BIGNUM *ret);
> ```
>
> **BN_bin2bn** sets |*ret| to the value of |len| bytes from |in|, interpreted as a **big-endian number**, and returns |ret|. If |ret| is NULL then a fresh |BIGNUM| is allocated and returned. It returns NULL on allocation failure.
>
> ```
>  int BN_mod_exp(BIGNUM *r, const BIGNUM *a, const BIGNUM *p, 
>      const BIGNUM *m, BN_CTX *ctx);
> ```
>
> **BN_mod_exp** sets |r| equal to |a|^{|p|} mod |m|. It does so with the best algorithm for the values provided and can run in constant time if |BN_FLG_CONSTTIME| is set for |p|. It returns one on success or zero otherwise.

And they produce different results.

What should I do about this? What would be your next thing to check?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is just C# dev (with OpenSSL validating the results), then you should move to [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/). Its cleaner and easier to use. Operator overloading in C++ makes doing big math sooo much easier (speaking from experience).

Comment: Usually you work with public and private keys parts. So there's six objects in play for unauthenticated DH (ephemeral-ephemeral): `pubA`, `privA`, `sharedA`, `pubB`, `privB`, `sharedB`. It looks like you are missing some pieces. Authenticated DH (ephemeral-static) adds long terms keys for A and B, so there's four more pieces that appear to be missing.

Comment: *"I'm implementing a Diffie-Hellman key exchange algorithm between an embedded device..."* - for the low powered, resource constrained devices, you usually avoid DH because its too costly. In this case, a preshared key protocol is often used, like Preshared Key (PSK). PSK is a [Password Authenticated Key Exchange (PAKE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password-authenticated_key_agreement). Secure Remote Password (SRP) is another PAKE, but its underlying problem is Diffie-Hellman (which you usually avoid).

Comment: @jww, we have the access to code level at both sides, but application of diffie-hellman between those devices is a must that we don't decide. And that makes openssl (which is also used in other sections of the embedded side) more important for us. the question is, how can we ensure that both sides are calculating the same when inputs are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using BouncyCastle Crypto Library's BigInteger methods. Couldn't tell System.Numerics.BigInteger that we are using big endian unsigned chars for initialization.